# Exercise $17$ $(e)$ on Marcus' Number Fields, Chapter $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Exercise $17$ on Marcus' Number Fields, Chapter $4$, has $9$ items (from $a$ to $i$). I got stuck at item $e$.

[image]

[image]

(The notation is the following: Whenever $L$ is a normal extension of $K$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $\text{Gal}\left (L/K\right )$, for every subset $X\subset L$ the set $X_H$ is the set of elements of $X$ fixed pointwise by $H$).

The second and the third part of the exercise are easy, because we are supposing that $Q$ is unramified, therefore if $PS=QI$ then $Q$ is coprime to $I$ and hence $Q+I=S$. If the first part were true, the third part follows immediately, so we only have to prove the first part.

I tried to use that $\sigma \left (t\right )\equiv t\pmod U$ for every $\sigma \in \text{Gal}\left (M/L\right )=E$ and then use the trace $T_{L}^M$, but this only leads to $\left | E\right | T\subseteq S+U$.

I also tried to use the fact that $U$ is a maximal ideal of $T$ and $S$ is not included in $U$, but then I could not prove that $S+U$ is an ideal of $T$.

Any help?

Comment: I wish Marcus's book was retypeset with TeX.

Comment: The codifferent fractional ideal is $\mathcal{O}_L^{\wedge}= \{ b \in L, \forall a \in \mathcal{O}_L, Tr_{L/K}(ba) \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.  Take a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $a$ and set $M_{i,j} = \sigma_i(a_j)$. Then $(M^\top M)_{j,l} =Tr_{L/K}(a_j a_l)$. For $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathcal{O}_K$ a prime ideal, $\mathfrak{p} \nmid (\mathcal{O}_L^{\wedge})^{-1}$ iff $M^\top M$  is inversible in $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{p}$, thus all the rows of $M$ are different modulo $\mathfrak{p}$ and the inertia group is trivial and $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified.

Comment: @lhf It now has been! Moreover, the nicely typeset second edition is in the Springer Yellow Sale 2019. Christmas has come very early this year. :)