# Marcus Number fields exercise 17 chapter 4

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I know this question has already been posted, but I don't manage to understand the comments.

[Exercise $17$ $(e)$ on Marcus' Number Fields, Chapter $4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529763/exercise-17-e-on-marcus-number-fields-chapter-4)

My problem is exactly the same as the one the other user has pointed out: I managed to show that $|E|T \subset S+U$ , but I have no idea how to proceed to conclude.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

$U$ is a maximal ideal so $S + U$ is either $U$ or the whole ring $T$.  $S + U \not\subseteq U$ (take any $s \not\in Q$), so $S + U = T$.